# Any way to use Pipeline and DataflowPipelineOptions instances inside ParDo?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

As it is apparent that Pipeline and DataflowPipelineOptions instances can be used inside ParDo when written in static block only.Since, processElement() is not static. Therefore, ParDo can't accommodate any logic inside this function which deals with objects of Pipeline and DataflowPipelineOptions.

Sample :

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
{
  PCollection<String> dummy=p.apply("dummy"); // It will fail with a SerializableException (What I want to do)
}
```

So, just wanted to check whether the same can be made possible by calling a static function from ParDo itself.

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
{
   logicCaller();     // It's a static function
}
```

The logicCaller() static method can contain anything from creation of a simple PCollection to any ParDo block execution having some logical steps inside.

I tried this way around and the function got called successfully as well. The weird behaviour was that everything got executed inside that static function but the ParDo part got skipped without any error or exception.

Any insights?

Comment: You can not (or at least should not) start new pipelines from inside functions of an existing pipeline. Pipelines are extremely heavyweight objects; if you've used Hadoop, imagine creating a new Hadoop job for every element in your mapper or reducer.

Comment: Please explain your end-to-end use case so we can recommend a better approach.

Comment: Hi @jkff I'm still trying to design a module for dependant jobs to run in sequence. I had thought a workaround for this. Suppose, I have two jobs to run in sequence. I would create two dummy PCollections accommodating two different job logics. I would  pass a dummy sideinput from the ParDo applied on first dummy PCollection to the ParDo applied on second PCollection. This way my second job would wait for the first job to complete. But, the problem is that I have some PCollections to create in my first job and it's ParDo is not allowing me to do so.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to design a general-purpose way to run one job after another job completely runs. To save you the time, I'm going to say straight up that this is impossible within the Beam model and you won't be able to achieve this. However, if you have a concrete task you're trying to accomplish, please create a new question with that, and maybe there's a way to achieve the proper kind of sequencing in that particular context.